# Assign html attributes to url link in CakePHP's HtmlHelper's image

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, html-helper

I am trying to find a way to set attributes to the link URL generated by the image method of CakePHP's HtmlHelper. I'm using CakePHP 2.2.1

For example, the following code:

```
echo $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", array(
    "alt" => "Brownies",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6)
));
```

generates:

```
<a href="/recipes/view/6">
    <img src="/img/recipes/6.jpg" alt="Brownies" />
</a>
```

How can I add attributes to the href tag. Say, for example, class='picture' to look like:

```
<a href="/recipes/view/6" class='picture'>
    <img src="/img/recipes/6.jpg" alt="Brownies" />
</a>
```

Comment: Raisen: Please ignore the -2 votes on my answer below. It is correct and has been tested. I use it regularly, and as of a year ago, I asked the same question you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add HTML attributes to the Anchor tag via the `Html->image` method - the way to do it is to put the `Html->image` within the `Html->link` method like so:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", array('alt' => 'Brownies')),
    array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6, array('escape'=>false', 'class'=>'picture')
);
```

You must also include the `'escpape'=>false` - otherwise your `<img...>` will be escaped, and it will show up like `&lt;img ... &gt;`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add any attribute to `HTML anchor tag` using `HtmlHelper`, then you can use it via:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
$this->Html->image("loading.gif", array('alt' => 'Brownies', 'border' => '0')),
array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6),  array('class' => 'picture', 'escape' => false));
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you are still looking for an answer, what you have to do is instead of using `$this->Html->image` with the optional URL attribute, you need to use `$this->Html->link` with the optional `escape = false` attribute where the title of the link is your image, utilizing `$this->Html->image`. What `escape = false` does is unescape special characters in the title of the link allowing you to use an image or other html element.

Here is an example

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image($image['Image']['file'], 'class' => 'image', 'alt' => $image['Image']['title'])),
'path/to/image', // or an array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'myaction')
 array('escape' => false));
```

You can add more image attributes such as the class and alt I have listed as well as more link attribute such as the escape I have listed.

Comment: Why are you just duplicating Dave's answer?

Comment: because the answer was voted down and PHP Developer commented that there was an error

Comment: It was before he fixed the mistake. You could easily see that by comparing your answer to his. They are identical (apart from the written part). Yours is even less correct as the class is attached to the wrong array. And you are using the wrong array keys for the url - they are not conventional.

Comment: the class is for the image, not the link so it is correctly attached. How are the url array keys wrong?

Comment: check out the most correct answer on this page - the one from @Dave

Comment: as far as I can tell our url array looks the same apart from my controller and action being cap which I was only using for emphasis. I will adjust answer as to not confuse readers. If that is not what you are talking about then I'm not sure. Either way, if my answer helps give the asker more of an explanation then so be it. I don't really care.

Comment: @bowlerae - I realize you're new to StackOverflow, so I'll assume it's just a mistake, and not intentional disregard of integrity, but as mark pointed out it's not a good idea to duplicate existing answers. (thanks, mark!)

Comment: I don't see why this needs to be voted down as it IS a correct answer the includes a little more detail. It is not incorrect or off topic.